# Convert Any to String in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have to log some param values to a log file (SQL Server 2005)

Is there an *universal* **`.ToString()`** method in SQL that could convert any kind of `object` to `string` in order to visualize a object value?

by eg. if I use `STR(@param)` it expects that @param be an float or integer value. and it fails when the @param is a varchar...

Comment: What is an "object value"? What data types are we talking about here, outside of strings, numbers and dates?

Comment: in .NET and Java we have a concept of "object" - any kind of object has a ToString method.

Comment: SQL Server is not OOP. So the concept of "object" is very different... this means a table, or view, or procedure, rather than a value.

Comment: I know that is not OOP, this why I ask, Aaron. And thank you for downvoting.

Comment: A column cannot be integer or float.  A SQL column has a single type. The insert statement to SQL is actually text. If that text does not parse to the data type of that column then SQL throws an error.  If you want a SQL column to accept string then use varchar or nvarchar for the SQL column.

Comment: Uh, I did not down-vote, why do you think it was me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to convert any parameter to a string using [`CONVERT()` or `CAST()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx):

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @param);
SELECT CAST(@param AS NVARCHAR(MAX));
```

Whether the conversion is meaningful is another thing.

Comment: say I have 100 places to put this code (I log param values)... every time I should think, what exactly type of param is?

Comment: Yes, parameters should be typed properly, rather than trying to make them generic, which can get you into trouble. This is not a one-size-fits-all scenario IMHO, whether you have 1 parameter, or 10, or 1000. If your procedure takes 100 parameters you may want to look into other methods (e.g. TVPs in SQL Server 2008+).

Comment: @serhio Your question is how to convert any parameter to string. How is that not an answer to the stated question?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `CAST()` and `CONVERT()` functions.